# Adding Markdown Syntax recognition to NotePad++ via UserDefineLang.xml

Tags: notepad++, plugins, highlighting, markdown, syntax

I want to add Markdown as a language to NotePad++. I've downloaded the **UserDefineLang.xml** file from [this](https://github.com/Edditoria/markdown_npp_zenburn) GitHub Project.

As I understand it, I am supposed to simply copy the **UserDefineLang.xml** file into the NotePad++ Program Folder and then restart NotePad++.

However, I still don't see any "Markdown" Option in the "Language" Menu. I've checked if there is a special local User-Folder for Notepad++ in my User-Directory, but I could not find any.

What am I doing wrong (as nobody else seems to have this problem)?

Comment: What version of Notepad++ are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same experience as you.  While the directions say to use the *program directory*, it should say to use this  `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++`

Either place or edit the **UserDefineLang.xml** in that location and it will work.

for a shortcut to that location do:
Click start, run, type **%APPDATA%\Notepad++**

Comment: Note that this doesn't apply to the portable version of notepad++